# Redirecionando dados de um formulário para outra página

Tags: php

Como faço para eu pegar os dados preenchidos em um formulário em uma página e mandar para outra página dentro dos `textbox` dela.

Comment: Tens algum código para exemplo ?

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que pretende fazer? Tem algum código?

Comment: Eu tenho 2 formularios em paginas diferentes e gostaria de mandar os dados de uma formulario para o outro na outra pagina, já preenchendo o formulario que eu vou mandar os dados no textbox

Answer (score 2):

Você pode acessar pelo:

```
$_POST['nome-do-campo']
```

Se o seu formulário tiver com o método GET você usa o:

```
$_GET['nome-do-campo']
```

Pra preencher o `textarea` você pode fazer assim:

```
<textarea><?php echo $_POST['nome-do-campo'] ?></textarea>
```